# Bar Button Items Weirdly Offset in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

As of Xcode 6 beta 3, there seems to be no padding on my bar button items, and they are pushed all the way to the edges. I am using size classes (single storyboard). When I investigated the storyboard further, it appears that the spot where the bar button item goes is moved off of the navbar somehow. Has anyone else seen this? It happens no matter which layout I select (photo below is on Any/Any).

Here's an image of how it looks in the simulator:

[image: simulator]

And this is what I see on the storyboard:
[image: storyboard]

Comment: Check your layout constraints

Comment: Try in Beta 4, which is out as of your posting.

Comment: @SantaClaus indeed, it did fix the issue. I posted here just before I saw beta 4 was out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Beta 4 fixed this issue.